# How to upload a text file using Python-Requests without writing to disk

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I would like to send a file in a `POST` request using Python's Requests library, in Python 3. I'm trying to send it like so:

```
import requests

file_content = 'This is the text of the file to upload'

r = requests.post('http://endpoint',
    params = {
        'token': 'api_token',
        'message': 'message text',
    },
    files = {'filename': file_content},
)
```

The server responds that no files were sent, however. Should this work? Most examples involve passing a file object, but I don't want to have to write the string out to disk just to upload it.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

It turns out, the reason it wasn't working had nothing to do with the file contents, but rather that I was sending the request over HTTP, rather than HTTPS, which was losing the entire body of the request.

Comment: I think you should mark ForceBru's answer as accepted. This is a correct answer to your question. That it doesn't answer your underlying problem is not relevant.

Answer (score 15):

The [`requests` docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) provide us with this:

> If you want, you can send strings to be received as files:

```
>>> url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
>>> files = {'file': ('report.csv', 'some,data,to,send\nanother,row,to,send\n')}

>>> r = requests.post(url, files=files)
>>> r.text
{
  ...
  "files": {
    "file": "some,data,to,send\\nanother,row,to,send\\n"
  },
  ...
}
```

I posted it as another answer as it involves a different approach.

Comment: Nice!  Thanks, need to write some tests, changing the name/data each time.

Answer (score 6):

Why not use `cStringIO`?

```
import requests, cStringIO

file_content = 'This is the text of the file to upload'

r = requests.post('http://endpoint',
    params = {
    'token': 'api_token',
    'message': 'tag_message',
    },
    files = {'filename': cStringIO.StringIO(file_content)},
)
```

I think `requests` uses some methods similar to ones we use with files. [`cStringIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) provides them.

---

Example of usage

```
>>> from cStringIO import *
>>> a=StringIO("hello")
>>> a.read()
'hello'
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Since I'm using Python 3, though, it's in the `io` module: `io.StringIO`